# Mutating functions and Properties

Tags: swift

I have a struct Town

with a population of 11

```
 struct Town {
    var population: Int = 11 {
        didSet(oldPopulation){
            print("The population has changed to \(population) from \(oldPopulation)")
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a mutating function

```
mutating func changePopulation(amount: Int) {
    population += amount     
}
```

I created a zombie class that calls a function that decreases population by 10

```
final override func terrorizeTown() {
    guard var town = town else {
        return
    }
    town.population <= 0 ? print("no people to terrorize") : town.changePopulation(amount: -10)

    super.terrorizeTown()
}
```

when I run this i the main.swift file

```
var myTown = Town()
var fredTheZombie = Zombie()
fredTheZombie.name = "Fred"
fredTheZombie.town = myTown

//myTown.changePopulation(amount: 0)
print(myTown.population)

fredTheZombie.terrorizeTown()
print(myTown.population)
```

What I don't understand is the results..

```
11
The population has changed to 1 from 11
Fred is terrorizing a town!
11
```

Why is it that when I print (myTown.population) again do i receive a value of 11, when I have called a mutating function on the property. I don't understand.. should the result not be 1, why do i get 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the line `guard var town = town` makes a *copy* of your Town object. Hence, it is the copy that is mutated.

Comment: To clarify just a bit. It's not the `guard` specifically. It's any assignment with a value type (a `struct` is a value type). Value types in Swift get copied when you assign a value to another.

Comment: Be that as it may, the line I cited is that cause of the phenomenon, and thus answers the "why" question that was posed.

Comment: My clarification is for the OP and other viewers. I assumed you already knew that.